# How to set the --compressed curl command option using curl_easy?

Tags: libcurl

When I run `curl --help` I see the following option available:

> `--compressed`    Request compressed response (using deflate or gzip)

However, when I visit the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) on curl_easy's `setopt` command, I don't see an option to pass in this compressed flag.

How can I set `--compressed` using `curl_easy_setopt` please?

Comment: Remember that `--libcurl` is a good option for converting command lines to C code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--compressed` is equivalent to [`CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html).